# DIV positioning issue

Tags: css, css-float, css-sprites

After adding the karate image on this [page](http://gloucestercountykarate.com/martial-arts/) it cuts off some chunks off the logo. I tried using `z-index` and negative margins, yet it didn't solve the problem. I'd the logo to stay on top of the karate image. The CSS is as shown below:

```
#rack #header #logo {

    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: -54px;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z-index` works only with `position:relative` or `position:absolute`.

Use this,

```
#rack #header #logo {    
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: -54px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: First of all `z-index` of overlayed element must be bigger. If z-index of another element is not defined its enough to set `z-index` just positive. And also you can set negative `z-index` to display element behind others.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't hurt to use high positive (or more negative) integers for `z-index` so that later you can fit in as many `div`s as required between different layers.